# Using readline statically in C (compilation and linkage)

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, readline

I would like to link readline statically with my program and I found this page about readline compilation from source http://www.bioinf.org.uk/software/profit/doc/node17.html but I'm a bit confused about the process.
The page talks about a variable `READLINELIB` in the makefile but I don't find it.

Could someone show me the way to use readline statically in my program, what to put in my Makefile for compiling readline from source and link it with my program?

Thank you.

Comment: "The makefile" referred to in that page is the makefile for ProFit, not the makefile for the readline library. To compile readline from source, you need to get the readline source and then compile it - you can't compile it from source by putting something in your *own* makefile. If you're using Linux, chances are high you can just get the static libraries from your package manager, without the need to compile it.

Comment: Readline come with a *configure* and *Makefile*, so to compile it I just need to run `configure` and `make` without the `make install`?
What's the result of `configure && make` and what does `make install` do? I've tried to understand it by reading the makefile but it's quite complex.

Comment: `configure` auto-generates the makefile, `make` builds the library, and `make install` installs it. You'll want to do all three - if you want to use readline there's no reason to not install it. You don't need to understand the makefile - you just need to understand and then follow the installation instructions.

Comment: It's for a school project which I will run on machine where readline isn't installed and where I cannot install programs and libraries so really I  can't install it.

Comment: If you're linking it statically, then that doesn't matter - you only need the library installed on the machine where you build your project, not the one on which you run it. If you need to build it on your school machine, then you're just out of luck - you can't build projects with libraries you don't have on your machine. If you just don't have admin rights on your school machine, then you can install it into a directory you do have rights over, such as one in your home directory.

Comment: Why would it be inmpossible if I provide the sources for readline with my program? It's just normal C code, I should be able to link it statically with my program.

Comment: You obviously can't just "provide the sources" - you'd need to provide the build instructions and all the other components too. If you want to include 30,000 lines of code you didn't write in your school project, of course you can do this if you wish, but since you've said you don't understand even the makefile, you'll find this a challenging exercise. If your school computer doesn't have readline installed on it, I'd suggest a much more practical alternative is to just not use readline in your project - it's line editing, it can't be that important.

Comment: You might like to read here an search for "static": http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/README The souces you get here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/snapshot/readline-master.tar.gz All this comes from here: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: Since the source code for readline()` is readily available, just include it as another file in your project, Then do not #include <readline.h>  But do write your own header file (lets call it `myReadline.h`) for the file that contains the readline() function and #include "myReadline.h" in any files that call it.   I.E. no need to make it the least bit complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I figured out the proper way to do it, I using the `--prefix` option of the *configure* file I can tell where to put/install the library. The problem about installation was that I don't have the right to access other directories than my `$HOME`, so no problem doing this:

```
configure --prefix=$HOME/libreadline && make && make install-static
```

Then in my program I include the file from `$HOME/libreadline/include`.

To compile the main program I link the program with the archive libraries `$HOME/libreadline/lib/libreadline.a` and `$HOME/libreadline/lib/libhistory.a`.

Also since readline files uses directive like `#include <readline/readline.h>` which doesn't correspond to the location of the files, I must tell the compiler where to look for included files. To do this, before running gcc, I set the variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH` to `$HOME/libreadline/include`.

Finally, since readline uses ncurses dynamic library I must tell the compiler to dynamically link it with my program. It might be the case of termcap too...

The overall process looks like:

```
configure --prefix=$HOME/libreadline && make && make install-static
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/libreadline/include
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c $HOME/libreadline/lib/libreadline.a $HOME/libreadline/libhistory.a -lncurses -ltermcap
```

I was confused about what `make install` do, it only copy files to the location provided by the *configure*, by default it installs in system directories like */usr/include*, etc... but providing the `--prefix` option make install will copy all files in the specified directory.

Installation is just copying compiled program, libraries, doc, etc to a certain location, by default standart system directories, if you don't have access to those directories like me you could "install" it in your own directory and then do whatever you wan't with it.

I could have installed the dynamic library instead the static one, but then I would have to modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. get readline source

   ```
   wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/snapshot/readline-master.tar.gz

   tar zxvf readline-master.tar.gz

   cd readline-master/
   ```
2. examples folder does not have Makefile, which is generated using Makefile.in script.
   following steps build static & dynamic libs & puts them inside /usr/local/bin

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   - may have to install curses as "sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev"
3. Use following make file (strip down version from examples folder)
   (Make sure tab is honored otherwise makefile will not work)

   ```
   RM = rm -f
   CC = gcc
   CFLAGS = -g -O

   INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include
   LDFLAGS = -g -L/usr/local/lib
   READLINE_LIB = -lreadline
   TERMCAP_LIB = -ltermcap

   .c.o:
       ${RM} $@
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<

   SOURCES = rlversion.c

   EXECUTABLES = rlversion

   OBJECTS = rlversion.o

   all: $(EXECUTABLES)
   everything: all

   rlversion: rlversion.o
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ rlversion.o $(READLINE_LIB) $(TERMCAP_LIB)

   clean mostlyclean:
       $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(OTHEROBJ)
       $(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)

   rlversion.o: rlversion.c
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was in need of libraries libreadline.a, libhistory.a for both 64 and 32 bit versions.
The answer provided by Rajeev Kumar worked for me. ( Had a little trouble finding and installing libncurses).
For 32-bit versions, using https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib32readline-dev, the following command worked for me.

```
sudo apt install lib32readline-dev
```

So it is hoped that for 64 also, it works

```
sudo apt install libreadline-dev
```